# Why is auth token not set in mobx store after login, and reroute to next component

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react, core-ui

I am using CoreUI with React Router DOM, React Router DOM config, Mobx and Mobx react.

I have written a login function in my store which stores the auth token from the server in session storage (using sessionStorage.setItem('token',token)) after successful login.

The problem, is that the next component I route to after login does a javascript fetch on componentDidMount, and sends the bearer auth token in the headers.

However, the issue that I am running into is that the auth token is undefined when the fetch occurs (sessionStorage.getItem('token')). It only shows up after I refresh the page. It is like the component loads and is rendered before the auth token has been saved.

I wonder if this is due to asynchronous calls.

In my login component I have this function:

```
logIn = async () => {
    const { sessionStore: ss } = this.props.RootStore;
    let login = await this.ss.login();
    if(login) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  }
```

Then, in my next component (Dashboard), I have:

```
componentDidMount() {
      const { companyStore : company, sessionStore : ss } = this.props.RootStore;
      if(ss.companySetup === false) {
        company.getDefaultCompany('set');
      }
    }
```

In the function getDefaultCompany, I check if sessionStorage.getItem('token') is set, and if so, add it to the header. But it comes back undefined. If I refresh the page, the token is set and goes with the fetch call.

I am stumped.

Comment: Can you send login function code?